# app is crashing without any error

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to integrate the google map sdk and followed [this link to start from google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#getting_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios). I have created the API key and used it in `appDelegate`. I wrote below code in my `ViewController.m` and I have imported all the frameworks required, and also put the `-ObjC` in other linker flag but still the app is crashing on run time. I have used breakpoints but no log is been shown up. Below is the entire code and haven't used any outlet.

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                            longitude:151.20 zoom:6];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera]; // crashing here, even gave different frames rather CGRectZero
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.view = mapView_;
    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
    marker.title = @"Sydney";
    marker.snippet = @"Australia";
    marker.map = mapView_;
}

@end
```

**[DEMO SAMPLE LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B62pT4Le2is4MDYtVGkzalhPMHc/edit?usp=sharinghttps://drive.google.com/file/d/0B62pT4Le2is4MDYtVGkzalhPMHc/edit?usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the code and run it. It works perfectly well. Just remove the old app and clear the target. Re-install the app. It should work fine.

Comment: which xcode version and iOS simulator you are using..?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you pass CGRectZero to the frame of the map?

Try the following code:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                        longitude:151.20 zoom:6];

mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320) camera:camera]; // crashing here
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:mapView_];

// Creates a marker in the center of the map.
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
marker.title = @"Sydney";
marker.snippet = @"Australia";
marker.map = mapView_;

}
```

Comment: mapView_ is an IBOutlet for the viewController? If it is, remove that line and add  mapView_.camera=camera;

Comment: @Ricky- i haven't used any IBOutlet

Comment: Please show me the entire code for your view controller. Edit the question. If possible, please upload the project to testFlight and Link here.

Comment: @Ricky- i have uploaded to google drive. see if you can access it

Comment: I have downloaded the project and I edited the code as per above. It works perfectly on my end.

Comment: @Ricky- which xcode version and iOS simulator you are using..?